# Attach Kryptonite Messenger Mini+

Tags: lock

I got a Kryptonite Messenger Mini+ with a rear wheel extender. Really great design except for one thing: there's no way to clip it to the frame. The clip that I have depends on fitting on the straight side of the U, which would make using the extender impossible.

Is there a convenient way to attach this to the frame?

[image]

Additional description: the issue is that in the picture above, the right hand side is straight, and can accommodate the standard aluminum clip that Kryptonite sells. However, the aluminum clip is rigid, and cannot turn around curves, meaning I cannot put in on the left, and slide it onto the right side. The right side is curved (how it's held into the lock) and the clip mount cannot fit onto the right hand side. However, if I attach it on the left, then U-extender cannot slide past the clip.

Comment: Are you talking about a clip for transportation in the frame, or to support the lock when it's securing the bike? If the former I can't see why you can't fold the extender over and use put the straight side in the clip.

Comment: The extender is free to rotate right ?  So rotate it to the center of the lock and use the clip on the right-side leg as pictured ??   Or does the lock part only come off one leg and rotate around the other?   Does the extender slide up and around the bend on the shackle ?

Comment: A picture of the clip might help answer your question; even better a picture showing how the lock _doesn't_ fit in the clip...

Comment: I'll post a picture when I get home. I updated the description with more details.

Comment: Shock cord.  Maybe 2, to keep the extra thingie from wobbling.

Comment: How about a backpack? In personal experience I've always found U locks get in the way of your water bottle when attached within the triangle, if I can find my old bike I'll post a pic with the U Lock on the outside of the seat post, this didn't get in the way of anything

Comment: This is for commuting, so I don't have a water bottle, and I prefer my backpack to be light.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a convenient way to attach this to the frame?

According to Diane Craig at Kryptonite support:

> The Flex frame bracket will not work with the Messenger Mini +. We do not make a spline for the Messenger series to attach the lock to the bracket. The Transit H bracket will work it mounts to the handlebars and the lock hangs down"

[Pictures of the bracket in use](http://woohoobikes.com/en/locks-security/1961-kryptonite-h-bar-carrier-u-lock-lock-bracket-transit-720018000761.html) were few and did not include the Messenger Mini+.
[image]

Bracket empty
[image]

"convenient" is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: @RecursivelyIronic I'm sorry to edit my answer to a completely different answer after your comment (which is correct!) Stack Exchange fussed at me for trying to create a new answer after deleting my old answer - I did the best I could.

Comment: Cool, looks like this would work. I've already ordered a [Huldit mount from REI](https://www.rei.com/product/153816/huldit-u-lock-holder), which should work.  If it doesn't, I'll give this one a shot.